# how can i use child process to call python script that depends on other python scripts in nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process

i'm building an application using nodejs , and i need to call a python program which contains many files that depends on each other , so my question is , is child process useful in this siutuation or there are other ways to do this .

Ps: and for people who will come and tell me that this is a duplicate question , i couldn't find the answer to my question in the other questions as its not the same situation even though its the same question , thanks.

```
   const { spawn } = require('child_process')

const logOutput = (name) => (message) => console.log(`[${name}] ${message}`)

function run() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const process = spawn('python', ['./script.py', 'my', 'args']);

    const out = []
    process.stdout.on(
      'data',
      (data) => {
        out.push(data.toString());
        logOutput('stdout')(data);
      }
    );


    const err = []
    process.stderr.on(
      'data',
      (data) => {
        err.push(data.toString());
        logOutput('stderr')(data);
      }
    );

    process.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
      logOutput('exit')(`${code} (${signal})`)
      if (code !== 0) {
        reject(new Error(err.join('\n')))
        return
      }
      try {
        resolve(JSON.parse(out[0]));
      } catch(e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const output = await run()
    logOutput('main')(output.message)
    process.exit(0)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error during script execution ', e.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Why the java tag?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Does this fail? Can you share the error?

Comment: it's just a mistake xd

Comment: no the problem is i don't only need one python script to run my project , in fact the script is depending on other script (in the python project ) so my question is how do i integrate all of the code source of that python project , i hope i am clear

Comment: the problem is that it doesnt show anything as result the server doesnt return anything and is even taking forever to show anything